# Is there a deployment tool similar to Fabric written in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, fabric

I put together a mobile development stack that is almost entirely using Javascript on node.js. With the only exception of SASS (prefer it to LESS) and Fabric. I prefer not to pollute my development directory and as I have to combine and minify JS and CSS anyway, I thought I could also use node.js to serve my code.

I would like to reduce my dependence on Ruby and/or Python. I don't really use all features of Fabric so I have the hope of replacing it. But I couldn't find any similar tool written in Javascript.

All I need is to:

- Pull from git repository.
- Install depencies locally.
- Minify and combine JS/CSS invoking require.js/SASS.
- Run testsuite.
- Serve the code via node.js for hands-on or testing with Ripple.

Fabric might already be overkill, I only use it for my Python web projects because the necessary servers don't run on my machine, but that wouldn't be the case here. What would be the best way to handle this without Fabric?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've been pondering the same question myself.

The most promising direct candidate I've found so far is launch (https://github.com/bengourley/launch). However, it hasn't been updated in like a year, which makes me a little suspicious about its future status.

In the absense of obviously good solutions, I ended up solving the whole build/deployment problem, piece by piece in the following fashion:

- <del>After some trial and error, I removed `node_modules` from `.gitignore`. One of the implications is that you don't have to install dependencies locally, removing the second step ([try if reading this](http://www.mikealrogers.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html) convinces you as well).</del>

  - **Edit:** I no longer do this and instead keep `node_modules` in `.gitignore`. Just make sure `package.json` stays up-to-date (for tips, see ["Managing Node.js Dependencies with Shrinkwrap"](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/02/27/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/))
- I ended up automating JS/CSS processing, linting and test suite running with [grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt). Highly recommended.
- <del>I'm lazy and just now I'm adding the minified stuff into git (hopefully I will change this at some point).</del>

  - **Edit:** I no longer add minified stuff into git, but instead run `grunt` when deploying to do the minification

By doing so, I effectively eliminated some of the need for Fabric altogether, leaving only the actual deployment to be solved:

1. The best solution (deployment-wise) is to avoid running your own servers and use ready, cloud-solutions such as [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) or [Nodejitsu](http://nodejitsu.com/)
2. Alternatively, you could host your own node.js deployment tools. For instance you can install [Nodester](http://nodester.com/) on your own servers and use the provided APIs and tools.
3. On a Linux box, it is very easy to write one-liners that re-deploy a node.js app, so I don't feel like I need to use any extra tools (besides bash) for that.

That being said, I too would be glad to hear about better solutions.

**Edit:** just found out about deploy (https://github.com/visionmedia/deploy). Seems very promising. You could try that as well!

Comment: Thanks, [grunt](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt) looks interesting indeed. Just found [Jake](https://github.com/mde/jake) which seems to be fine, but grunt appears to be easier to understand and use.

Comment: Oh right! Jake seems nice as well. Looks like more CoffeeScript-oriented though. The syntax seems verbose without Coffee, but I could give it a try just to know my options.

Comment: CoffeeScript is actually bundled with Cake which is Make/Rake/Jake for CoffeeScript. Not sure if it has the same features though. Still awfully verbose.

Comment: @PeterThrowson added new tool: deploy (see the answer). Seems like it could be helpful too!

Comment: Please check out this blog post from Joyent in response to the Mikeal Rogers solution of putting node_modules in your git repository. http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/02/27/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/ I'm with Dave here. Source code goes in git. Compiled/derived/transpiled artifacts do not.

Answer (score 16):

[Flightplan](https://www.npmjs.org/package/flightplan) looks very interesting and is inspired by Fabric. Its documentation has extensive examples and is worth checking out.

Comment: I'm a long-time fabric user and I just tried this out for a project. It works great.

Comment: Been using flightplan for a while now...It's super simple to use.  Not as full-featured as capistrano, but easier to implement.  Here's my boilerplate config with forever or upstart: https://gist.github.com/learncodeacademy/35045e64d2bbe6eb14f9

Answer (score 3):

[stagecoach](https://github.com/punkave/stagecoach) does staging and deployment, with support for dependency installation and upstart scripts.

[Here's a blog post](http://justjs.com/posts/deploying-node-js-and-mongodb-in-production-with-stagecoach) about deploying node & mongo using stagecoach.

Answer (score 2):

Another javascript deployment tool is [shipitjs](https://github.com/shipitjs/shipit)

From their readme:

> Shipit is an automation engine and a deployment tool written for node / iojs.
>
> Shipit was built to be a Capistrano alternative for people who don't know ruby, or who experienced some issues with it. If you want to write tasks in JavaScript and enjoy the node ecosystem, Shipit is also for you.